# Give a geometric proof that $\frac{2\cdot3}{4} + \frac{2\cdot3}{16} + \frac{2\cdot3}{64} + \cdots + \frac{2\cdot3}{4^n} + \cdots = 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am suppose to give a "picture proof" for this but I am still having trouble proving it in the first place. I tried proof by induction but I do not think that is how I am suppose to answer the question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I swiped this illustration from [Wikipedia's article on geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series):

[image: Sum of 1/4 + 1/16 + 1/64 + …]

Perhaps it is suggestive?

Comment: I see what you mean by this, but I am having trouble with my exact proof.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Let S_0 be the rectangle with dimension(2x3);

```
S_n be the rectangle with dimension(2^(1-n),3x2^(-n));

A_required= Area coloured with pink, which is equivalent to:

           (2x3)/4+(2x3)/16+...    ;

A_complement= Area coloured with purple

            = Area complementary to A_required in S_0 /2;
```

We have:

A_required  = S_1 + S_2 + ...

A_complement= 2(S_2 + S_3 + ...)

So

A_required - A_complement/2 = S_1 = 3/2 --(1)

A_required + A_complement = 3

A_required/2 + A_complement/2     = 3/2 --(2);

(1)+(2),

(3/2)A_required=3

Therefore A_required=2

Comment: Also In reality, there must be a very tiny rectangle left at the up-right-hand corner, but with the fact that S_n=(2^(1-n),3x2^(-n))=0 when n tends to infinity, (lim n->infinity)S_n can be neglected.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Divide the equation
$$
\frac 64+\frac6{4^2}+\cdots = 2
$$
by $6$ to obtain 
$$
\frac 14+\frac 1{4^2}+\cdots = \frac 13
$$

For a geometrical proof, start with a unit square. Color one of the four quarters of the square. Then, repeat using one of the other quarters. 
Link to image:
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_PnLYRqe0k9g/Smp9INIigTI/AAAAAAAAAI0/gQyMxj1hry0/s1600-h/Sum+Of+Fractions+Inverse+Powers+of+4.png
==Alternative ways to proof it:==
This can be done using geometric series.
Another way is to multiply by $4$ and rewrite it:
$$
\frac 14+\frac 1{4^2}+\cdots =S\\
4S = S + 1\\
S=\frac 13
$$

Comment: Your geometric proof seems to be illustrating $\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + ... = \frac{1}{2}$, which is not the required result. Note that the measures of the side length of the smaller squares are labelled as less than they should be.

Comment: @Deepak I do not understand what you mean. The proof seems fine, could you please elaborate? The numbers represent areas, not side lengths.

Comment: @Ian I stand corrected. I misinterpreted the figure when I posted my comment in a sleep deprived state. I now realise that the areas, and not the side lengths, are being summed. The proof is correct and I withdraw my objections with apology.